# Python what does abs do? I have tried looking at different pages for help, however i cannot understand the jargon

Tags: python

I am a complete novice when it comes to Python and i just want to know what abs does. I have tried looking at different pages for help, however i cannot understand the jargon.

Thanks,
Louis.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#abs

Comment: sorry @iCodez but i dont think you read the jargon part?

Comment: @Luis - if you want to be good at programming, open your mind to strange looking messages like docstrings, stack traces, and read it as a child, which is used to not understand everything, but trying hard to gain whatever is waiting there.

Comment: believe me, i do try. its just that its seems that every other word doesn't make sense when reading some of these sources that people give me.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about learning how to read documentation

Comment: @juanchopanza thats great.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value

Comment: @juanchopanza, OK it's not a great question, but there's no need to be offensive or negative. I guess Louis simply doesn't know what the expression "absolute value" means. Although it's basic maths for many of us, English might not be his native language or he might simply not know that it's a general mathematical expression worth googling for.

Comment: @Bruno I am not being offensive or negative. This is not the place to ask that kind of question, and voting is the mechanism to deal with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> help(abs)
Help on built-in function abs in module __builtin__:

abs(...)
    abs(number) -> number

    Return the absolute value of the argument.
```

Also the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#abs)

If the number passed to the function is negative, it returns the positive. If it is positive, it returns it unchanged.

Think of it as removing the `-` negative sign.

```
>>> abs(2)
2
>>> abs(-2)
2
>>>
```